# When trying to get GlobalAppointmentId from AppointmentItem it sometimes returns null

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

We have a customer who experiences issues with our VSTO plugin when opening a new calendar appointment in outlook 2010.

this issue is not present on any of our own setups or at any other customer setups as far as we know.

what we have deduced is that when in our code we create an inspectorwrapper for the inspector object, this wrapper amongst other things accesses AppointmentItem.GlobalAppointmentID which so far has not been an issue, but this particular customer seems to run into an issue where GlobalAppointmentID is null.

i haven't been able to figure out if this is an error on our part or if it's an error in outlook, as far as i can tell the GlobalAppointmentID should be accessible, and has always been for us, on a new appointmentItem, but i have read some accounts where it is empty until the appointment is saved.

but i haven't been able to find any consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of Outlook generate new appointment id only when the meeting request is sent. Newer version of Outlook generate the id right off the bat immediate after the appointment is created even if a meeting request is never sent.

Comment: Upvoted. Didn't know about such differences. Which new versions of Outlook specifically?

Comment: 2013 and up for sure. Don't remember if 2010 did (or rather did not) do that.

Comment: yeah that's what i feared. the specific case we're seeing is in 2010. 

thanks for your answer @DmitryStreblechenko